# Sorting by IP then keep selecting records until I have 3 unique IPs

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm probably totally thinking about this harder then I have.

I have a report table in my database which has an IP-column (varchar), a Data-column (INT) and a Timestamp-column (TIMESTAMP).

I have to write a query where I sort by Timestamp DESC, then basically keep selecting records from the top until my resultset contains at least 3 unique IP's, in order of occurrence until a 4th IP is encountered.

For example:

```
IP         Data         Timestamp
1.1.1.0    0            1-1-2016
1.1.1.1    1            1-2-2016
1.1.1.1    2            1-3-2016
1.1.1.2    1            1-4-2016
1.1.1.3    1            1-5-2016
1.1.1.3    1            1-6-2016
```

In this case I want a result set of:

```
IP         Data         Timestamp
1.1.1.3    1            1-6-2016
1.1.1.3    1            1-5-2016
1.1.1.2    1            1-4-2016
1.1.1.1    2            1-3-2016
1.1.1.1    1            1-2-2016
```

Just for the use-case: The backend using this data will group the IPs, generate an average of the Data-column (basically flattening 1+ IP's back to 1), before its processed further.

I tried messing with GROUP BY, HAVING, Sub-query, I just can't figure it out while it seems so trivial!

EDIT: Some extra information

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip
FROM report
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Does not respect the first occurrence of an IP. For example if `1.1.1.3` is in the table as last and fourth occurrence, then DISTINCT will put the IP that should be on top order-wise as fourth (meaning its excluded from the LIMIT 3).

I then tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM report
WHERE ip in (
    SELECT DISTINCT ip
    FROM report
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

And that seems to work, but also highly unoptimized... LIMIT does not work in IN, MySQL rejects that. And when I would use LIMIT the problem outlined will happen.

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu Done, was already editing at the time you requested it. It seems like I found the solution, but it seems highly unoptimized.

Comment: The number of records are not fixed in the final result set. So LIMIT 3 won't work around I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following query should work if I understand your question correctly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM report
WHERE Timestamp >= (
    SELECT MIN(Timestamp) FROM (
        SELECT IP, MIN(Timestamp) as Timestamp
        FROM report
        GROUP BY IP
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 3
    ) x
)
ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
```

There may be ways to optimise this query, but I do not know if that is required in your scenario.

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07cb6/12) to test it in practice.

Comment: +1 because that SQL fiddle on it's own is already golden, thanks for that! Also seems very similar to the one I found, interesting trick too, thanks :)

Comment: I think you may get rid of the `DISTINCT` clause since you used `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu, thanks, you are correct. I removed it. The `GROUP BY` idea came later and I forgot to remove the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I was approaching in another way but I liked your approach. +1 for this

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT AVG(data), ip 
GROUP BY ip 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

I mean do the next task into the query as well. why would you want to list X distinct ips,  to up next group them by, group them by right away

Comment: The average was just an example to be honest, I have a lot more data-columns and perform all kinds of different calculations on them to flatten it back to one result before further processing, I don't want to do that in a query, hence I just want the raw results :)

Comment: imho you should treat this like a forum. the query I wrote would be just like the forum topics , if you want the raw data for an ip, it would be like the posts of a topic in a forum, the way to get that is a click on the topic (ip), and therefore that is another query